# How to perform chain state query for entries AND at a block hash?

Tags: polkadot-js, query, block-hash

I can do this to get all the structs in my storage:

```
        let queryResult = await api.query.mypallet.mystorage.entries();
```

but I want this query AT a specific block hash:

```
        let currentHeader = await api.rpc.chain.getHeader();
        let currentBlockNumber = currentHeader.number;
        let currentBlockHash = currentHeader.hash;
        console.log("currentBlockNumber=" + currentBlockNumber);
        console.log("currentBlockHash=" + currentBlockHash);

        let queryResult = await api.query.mypallet.mystorage.entries(); // ??????????
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entriesAt()` function has been deprecated so the correct way to do this is to get a separate instance of the api at the specified block hash.

```
const apiAtBlockHash = await this.api.at(blockHash);
let queryResult = await apiAtBlockHash.query.mypallet.mystorage.entries();
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `await api.query.mypallet.mystorage.entriesAt(blockHash)`?

The method `entriesAt` is defined [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/8282159f703a17d448c3bba8fa0ec5165209dfd6/packages/api/src/base/Decorate.ts#L739-L742)

Comment: Thank you!  However, VSCode is telling me that entriesAt() has been deprecated.